# Marshalling DefaultListModel does not write the data

Tags: java, swing, jaxb, marshalling

I am making a simple GUI where JLists are populated by DefaultListModels.

I have a class:

```
@XmlRootElement (name="data")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.PUBLIC_MEMBER)
public class Data {
    public DefaultListModel data1;
    public DefaultListModel data2;
```

And I am marshalling it in the normal way.

```
File file = new File("file.xml");
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Data.class);
Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();        
marshaller.marshal(this.parts, file);
```

The problem is that the XML file is looking like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<data>
    <data1>
        <size>6</size>
    </data1>
    <data2>
        <size>1</size>
    </data2>
</data>
```

In other words, it's not saving the data (which is a vector of Strings). Does this have something to do with the fact that DefaultListModel does not contain the actual vector of strings? Do I have to do this with Vector instead?

Comment: I'm surprised it managed to give you the size element. Can you provide a sample XML of what you expect ?

Comment: <data1>
        <size>6</size><string>value1</string><string>value2</string>....
    </data1>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `DefaultListModel` class is the underlying model of a GUI component (`JList`). Your business data is represented by your `Data` class. I suggest to put there the Vector of Strings and then handle them in a `DefaultListModel`. You can marshall/unmarshall on that, because the JAXB framework does not know about the DefaultListModel type, but it will handle basic Java type.

```
@XmlRootElement (name="data")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.PUBLIC_MEMBER)
public class Data {
    public List<String> data1;
    public List<String> data2;
```